# How to use $npm_config_ in package.json?

Tags: reactjs, npm, environment-variables, package.json, create-react-app

I'm using `create-react-app` for my React project (ejected), and I've configured a proxy in `package.json`. But I don't want to have my credentials committed in this file. So I've added to npm using `npm config set my_user xxxx`.
I can see them in my ~/.npmrc, too.

```
"proxy": {
  "/api/v3/": {
    "target": "https://ourstagingserver.nl/",
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "ssl": false,
    "secure": false,
    "headers": {
      "username": "$npm_config_my_user",
      "password": "$npm_config_my_pass"
    }
  },
```

This doesn't work. The username and password are not used in the proxy requests.

But if I add this to "scripts":

```
"hello": "echo $npm_config_my_user $npm_config_my_pass
```

and run `npm run hello`, both are echoed...

Any ideas? Is this supposed to work or am I doing it wrong?

Thx! Gijs

Answer (score 1):

I didn't figure out the use of `$npm_config_` variables for this purpose but I did solve the issue of using ENV variables for the proxy in create-react-app:

In `scripts/start.js` (line 62, below `const proxySetting = require(paths.appPackageJson).proxy`), add this:

```
proxySetting[Object.keys(proxySetting)[0]].headers.username = process.env.PROXY_USERNAME;
proxySetting[Object.keys(proxySetting)[0]].headers.password = process.env.PROXY_PASSWORD;
```

or you could loop over the objects in proxySetting and set the credentials for every object in there if you have multiple API's to proxy to:

```
Object.keys(proxySetting).forEach(function(proxy) {
  proxySetting[proxy].headers.username = process.env.PROXY_USERNAME;
  proxySetting[proxy].headers.password = process.env.PROXY_PASSWORD;
});
```

Note: `scripts/start.js` is a file that's generated by create-react-app